# Package installation issues

Tags: ros, installation, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am using ROS Fuerte and I want to get the Novint Falcon working as a joystick in ROS. I found this: https://wiki.qut.edu.au/display/cyphy/RosFalcon . I was able to download the files but I am unable to install them. I have a folder with the src folder and various other folders. How do I actually install this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190493/package-installation-issues/) by [pavanchirmade](https://answers.ros.org/users/19870/pavanchirmade/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Fuerte and older versions of ROS, you install packages by adding them to your ROS_PACAKGE_PATH environment variable; either by adding them directly or by adding them to a folder that is already on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

In your case, you should have a `rosfalcon` directory which contains the source and build files, and you should add the full path to that directory to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0